# Java - Selenium Firefox Driver - cannot click on specific button in modal

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-firefoxdriver

I want my program to log into indeed.ca (this is working, as long as you enter correct user credentials), navigate to a specific job posting(working), click on the first orange apply button(working), a modal pops up.

**Then I want to click on the blue apply button in modal that appears. This is not working. I have commented out my attempt at this portion of the program.**

Any help would be much appreciated.

```
import java.io.IOException;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;



public class Testing {

 public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    //enter location of gecko driver   
    System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "C:\\Users\\Padoga\\Documents\\geckodriver-v0.18.0-win64\\geckodriver.exe");

    FirefoxDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();

    //login works correctly (given that you use proper credentials)
    driver.get("https://secure.indeed.com/account/login?service=my&hl=en_CA&co=CA");
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"signin_email\"]")).sendKeys("abc@gmail.com");
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"signin_password\"]")).sendKeys("enterPassword");
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"loginform\"]/button")).click();  

    //once logged in navigate to specific job
    driver.navigate().to("https://ca.indeed.com/cmp/KGHM-International-Ltd./jobs/Financial-Analyst-7a08f1634e7d5c5c");

    //clicking on first apply button(orange button) works correctly
    Thread.sleep(3000);
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"apply-state-picker-container\"]/div[1]/span[1]")).click();

    //below not working, trying to click on apply button(blue apply button) in popup modal
    //I've tried so many different xpaths and ids none seem to be triggering the apply button in modal 
    Thread.sleep(3000);
    driver.switchTo().frame("indeedapply-modal-preload-iframe");
    driver.findElement(By.id("apply")).click();

 } 
}
```

And here is the various html / javascript?  that I have been trying to click on
i.e used as By.id, By.xpath, or By.className, none are working
The below code does not show up when I inspect the page source, only when I inspect the blue apply button in the modal that pops up after clicking the orange apply button, do I see the below code:

```
<div class="button_outter" id="apply-div">
    <div class="button_inner">
        <input class="button_content" id="apply" type="submit" name="apply" value="Apply">
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you add some implicit wait and try the same code?

Comment: I tried that a while ago, didn't fix issue,      //        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20);
//        WebElement element = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.id("apply")));

Comment: any recommendations santhosh?

Comment: Consider updating the question with relevant HTML. Thanks

Comment: I am checking ..

Comment: thank you santhosh, Debanjan I've added some HTML code I think may be relevant: full html available at https://ca.indeed.com/cmp/KGHM-International-Ltd./jobs/Financial-Analyst-7a08f1634e7d5c5c

Comment: There are iframes in between. We need to switch to those frames before clicking on that button

Comment: I had previously tried to switch frames but it did not seem to solve it, see my edits to my question please santhosh, I have tried switching frames. And still not working

Comment: Hi.., Yes.., switch to iframe is not working. Might be the html dom may not be per the standards, As i can see separate body tags. As a work around, we can use sendkeys to click on the apply button. If you are interested in this approach i will post an answer accordingly

Comment: Yes please Santhosh, that would be great.  Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tried using the switch to Iframe, but this is not working in this case. Can you check the below sendkeys approach after clicking the first apply button.

```
 Actions act = new Actions(driver);
 act.sendKeys(Keys.TAB, Keys.TAB, Keys.TAB, Keys.TAB, Keys.ENTER);
```

or

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//body")).sendKeys(Keys.TAB, Keys.TAB,Keys.TAB, Keys.TAB, Keys.ENTER);
```

**Update:** It seems, second recommendation actually worked for this case.

Hope this helps. Thanks.

Comment: thanks so much Santhosh, your first recommendation doesn't work, but your second recommendation works great.  I just edited your second solution, as you added an extra bracket at the end.   Appreciate all your help.  Padoga

Answer (score 1):

You need to switch to the `iframe` firtst then call `click()` method on the **`Blue` Apply** button as follows:

```
    driver.switchTo().frame(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//iframe[contains(@src,'https://apply.indeed.com/indeedapply/resumeapply')]")));
    //perfrom other actions
    //finally click on Blue Apply button
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='apply']")).click();
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems the index order of the iframes is backwards, at least that's what it looks like to me.  I was able to click the "Blue Apply Button" using the following java code:

```
driver.get("https://ca.indeed.com/cmp/KGHM-International-Ltd./jobs/Financial-Analyst-7a08f1634e7d5c5c");
wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
//on my screen I had to scroll down to the orange apply button
WebElement applyButton  = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.className("indeed-apply-button")));
((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", applyButton);
applyButton.click();
Thread.sleep(1000);
driver.switchTo().frame(1);
driver.switchTo().frame(0);
driver.findElement(By.id("applicant.name")).sendKeys("My First Name is");
driver.findElement(By.id("apply-div")).click();
```

Comment: Thanks smit9234, this solution works great, and is great way of switching frames, and finding / selecting actual elements in new frame.  I was using firefox driver which I think doesn't need you to scroll down, or the Javascript Executor.  Does your code assume someone is using HtmlUnitDriver?

Comment: I was testing it in chrome, which was throwing an "no element found" exception. Once I implemented the javascript executor it worked fine.  Not sure what would happen using htmlunitdriver.

Comment: Hey smit9234,  your code was working great, but as of a week ago I think Indeed.ca changed something and your code: driver.switchTo().frame(1);
driver.switchTo().frame(0); no longer seems to work, any idea, how to fix.